# Unable to use FindWindowA in CLR C++ Project

Tags: c++, clr

I can't use FindWindowA In a clr project as it gives me a bunch of errors, this is my code.

I am trying to make a trainer for a game.

This is so when you left click the button it finds the window

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {



    HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "Random process");

}
```

However when I run this I get 2 unresolved external symbols these are the errors

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "extern "C" struct HWND__ * __stdcall 
FindWindowA(char const *,char const *)" (?FindWindowA@@$$J18YGPAUHWND__@@PBD0@Z) referenced in 
function "private: void __clrcall Project1::MyForm::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class 
System::EventArgs ^)" (? 
button1_Click@MyForm@Project1@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)    Project1     
C:\Users\user\source\repos\Project1\Project1\MyForm.obj 1   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2028 unresolved token (0A000273) "extern "C" struct HWND__ * __stdcall 
FindWindowA(char const *,char const *)" (?FindWindowA@@$$J18YGPAUHWND__@@PBD0@Z) referenced in 
function "private: void __clrcall Project1::MyForm::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class 
System::EventArgs ^)" (? 
button1_Click@MyForm@Project1@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)    Project1     
C:\Users\user\source\repos\Project1\Project1\MyForm.obj 1
```

Comment: Probably not related to the error, but why not `FindWindowW`?

Comment: Sorry Don't Really know the difference would you mind explaining if its not a bother?

Comment: @JoeMama `FindWindowA()` is for ANSI strings, `FindWindowW()` for Unicode strings. As for the linker error, are you linking in `User32.lib`? Or, are you using PInvoke to reach `FindWindow`?

Comment: I'm using Windows.h and TlHelp32.h as my #includes however if thats not what you mean I don't know what you are talking about my apologies

Comment: Where is `FindWindowA` located?  The linker (which is where the errors are coming from) is basically asking that question, since you provided no indication of where this function is found (this is where the `User32.lib` comes into play).  When you compile the program, all the header file does is tell the compiler "there is a function called `FindWindowA` out there somewhere, so compile with no errors and trust the programmer".  So the compiler is successful -- but the linker is the one that really wants to know where the function resides, thus the error at link time.

Comment: So I should include User32 lib to fix this, I'm sorry I'm a bit slow if this is not what is being implied

Comment: Okay I just figured out how to make it work I had to add user32lib to additional dependencies in the linker tab, thank you so much for your help with understanding what was wrong this helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding userlib32 to additional dependencies in the linker tab, thank you so much for everyones help in understanding what was wrong

If you need to fix this go to your project properties Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies->Edit and then add userlib32